# How to have different settings for local development and production in .net Aspire

Tags: .net, .net-8.0, dapr, dotnet-aspire

Let's say I want to use a Redis container when running it locally and Azure Cache for Redis in production (when deployed to Azure Container Apps).

Or it could be dapr state store plus pubsub locally and, Azure Cosmos DB plus Service Bus in production.

How would I set this up? In every demo and documentation I found so far, "azd up" is used to deploy the application with the same settings as local dev.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really supported yet but we expect this will be easy to do by v1. The only way to get around this today is to change the scaffolded bicep and change it to spin up those services. It's on the roadmap to support this in a more first class way.

Comment: You should also add custom Dashboard themes :P. I want to tease a Java/Mac fanatic at work that complains he can't make any sense of Elastic log searches, with OTEL data sent from *Python* scripts. I already did the last part, just redirect Python auto-instrument data to Dashboard's OTLP endpoint